# Persisting Serializable Objects in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, mysql, hibernate

I am attempting to persist objects that contain some large `Serializable` types. I want Hibernate to automatically generate my DDL (using Hibernate annotations). For the most part, this works, but the default database column type used by Hibernate when persisting these types is `tinyblob`. Unfortunately, this causes crashes when attempting to persist my class, because these types will not fit within the length of `tinyblob`.

However, if I manually set the type (using `@Column(columnDefinition="longblob")`, or more portably `@Column(length=500000)`), it works fine. Is there any way to make the default binary type `longblob` instead of `tinyblob`, so that I don't need to manually specify the `@Column` annotation on each field?

ExampleClass.java:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
  @Column(columnDefinition="longblob")
  ExampleSerializable ser1;

  @Column(columnDefinition="longblob")
  ExampleSerializable ser2;

  ...
}
```

ExampleSerializable.java:

```
public class ExampleSerializable implements java.io.Serializable
{
  // MANY Fields
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Since there seems to be some confusion: annotating each field with `@Column(columnDefinition="longblob")` (or more portably: `@Column(length=500000)`), already works. I am looking for a solution that does not require me to annotate each and every field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (didn't test it) that Hibernate will generate a tinyblob, blob, mediumblob column depending on the column length (respectively 255, 65535, 16777215) which defaults to 255. I would try to specify it (and this would be a portable solution).

Now, if really you want to force things, you'll have to extend the MySQL dialect (but this will harm portability).

Comment: Is there a way to specify a default column length? Having to specify the column length on each member is no easier than having to specify `longblob` on each member.

Comment: @VeeArr: It's maybe not easier, but it's portable (`longblob` might not exist with another database). Regarding the length of a `Column`, this default is defined by the JPA specification and patching the persistence-api.jar can't be a good advice. I don't mean to be rude, but I think you're expecting too much magic.

Comment: Ah, yes, I understood your point that it is more portable (and thus better than my original solution). I was addressing the issue that it didn't solve my problem, though. But thanks for your response!